# When only eventually constant sequences are convergent?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space whose convergent sequences are eventually constant. Is there a description of such spaces. How ''far'' these spaces from Stonean ones?

Comment: $\beta \mathbb{N}$ (the Stone-Čech compactification of the discrete space $\mathbb{N}$) has this property, but is also extremally disconnected, hence Stonean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Norbert, I don't think that there is a reasonable description of such spaces. Indeed, they properly contain spaces $K$ for which the Banach space $C(K)$ is [Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_space) and this class is far from being fully delineated. For example, there are connected, compact spaces $K$ for which $C(K)$ is indecomposable, hence Grothendieck.