# A sequence $ (x_{n})$ is convergent in $X$ $\iff$ $ (x_{n})$ is a stationary sequence. Does $X$ have to be discrete?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space so that a sequence $ (x_{n})$ is convergent in $X$ $\iff$ $ (x_{n})$  is a stationary sequence. Does $X$ have to be discrete?

Does topology $ T = \left\{ X \subset \mathbb{R} | \operatorname{card} (X^{c}) \leq \aleph_{0}   \right\} $ work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergent sequence in co-countable topology iff sequence is eventually constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1768552/convergent-sequence-in-co-countable-topology-iff-sequence-is-eventually-constant)(Your proposed topology is called the cocountable topology, or the countable complement topology; Also, a more standard term for stationary sequence is eventually constant sequence)

Comment: Nitpick: You should replace $T$ with $T\cup \{\Bbb R\}.$.... BTW there is a non-empty compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points (e.g. $\beta \Bbb N \setminus \Bbb N$) in which  the only convergent sequences are "eventually constant".

Comment: Also related: [When is any convergence sequence is stationary?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217704/when-is-any-convergence-sequence-is-stationary) and [When only eventually constant sequences are convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398597/when-only-eventually-constant-sequences-are-convergent)

Comment: The result mentioned by Daniel Wainfleet is proved in [Stone-Čech compactifications and limits of sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35310/stone-Čech-compactifications-and-limits-of-sequences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this topology works. Let $x_n \to x$. If it is not true that $x_n=x$ for all $n$ sufficiently large then there exist integers $n_1<n_2<..$ such that $x_{n_i} \neq x$ for all $i$. Consider the set $U=\mathbb R \setminus \{x_{n_i}: i\geq 1\}$. This is an open set containing $x$. Since$x_n \to x$ it must be true that $x_n \in U$ for all for all $n$ sufficiently large. This contradicts the fact that $x_{n_i} \notin U$ for any $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the topology you defined (the co-countable topology) has the property that all convergent sequences are eventually constant:

Suppose $(x_n)_n$ converges to $p \in X$ in the co-countable topology.
Define $C=\{x_n: x_n \neq p\}$ which is an at most countable subset of $X$, so $O:=X\setminus C$ is open in the co-countable topology, and as $p \notin C$ by definition, $p \in O$.

By the definition of convergence, there must be some index $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\forall n \ge N: x_n \in O$$

But it’s clear that $x_n \in O$ iff $x_n \notin C$ iff $x_n = p$, so that $$\forall n \ge N: x_n =p$$ which says that $(x_n)_n$ is eventually constant with value $p$.

And if $X$ is an uncountable set then the co-countable topology is a non-discrete topology on $X$ that nevertheless obeys the property that all convergent sequences are eventually constantly their limit.